# Are there any websites that walkthrough Nietzsche's work?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche

I have often seen sites dedicated to famous literary works that break down a composition and help explain it to the beginner. I've only taken one class on philosophy so I'm not going to understand some of the more obscure/indirect ideas behind his works. Does anyone know of any sources, preferably websites, that break down his books, ideally *The Birth of Tragedy* because that's where I wish to start.